# How do I rename photos based on their shotwell titles?

Tags: python, shotwell, photo-management

I recently gave ~200 photos numerical titles in Shotwell which describe their sequences--001, 002, etc. But I'd like for this sequence to be the same in the filenames, too, so that when I open the folder in Nautilus the photos are listed in order. I think Shotwell saved the title in the exif data somewhere. In fact, I finally found it using the Gnome image viewer, under XMP Other and photoshop:Headline. What I'd like is a way to read these Shotwell titles and have those used as the filenames. I could probably do this with Python if I knew how to access that metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a `apt-cache search exif`, and found (among other packages):

```
exiv2 - EXIF/IPTC metadata manipulation tool  
bins - Generate static HTML photo albums using XML and EXIF tags  
exif - command-line utility to show EXIF information in JPEG files  
exifprobe - Read metadata from digital pictures  
exiftags - utility to read Exif tags from a digital camera JPEG file  
jigl - Generates a static html photo gallery from one or more directories of images  
libexif-ruby1.9.1 - EXIF tag parsing Library for ruby1.9.1  
libimage-exif-perl - Perl module to extract EXIF information from image files  
libimage-exiftool-perl - Library and program to read and write meta information in multimedia files  
libimage-info-perl - allows extraction of meta information from image files  
metacam - extract EXIF information from digital camera files  
pyrenamer - mass file renamer written in PyGTK  
python-exif - Python library to extract EXIF data from tiff and jpeg files  
renrot - Rename and rotate files according to EXIF tags
```

So try [pyrenamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pyrenamer). If you can't make it do what you like, you might build your own tool with [python-exif](http://packages.ubuntu.com/python-exif)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally didn't know about 'apt-cache search'. I ended up writing something with python-exiv2, and it works!

Answer (score 5):

As there is no other answer showing *how* to actually rename photos with the titles added in `Shotwell`, here is a quick way to script it using bash, as you say in the comments that you already have a python alternative. There may well be other ways of doing it, but this one might be useful for someone.

As you have already given your pictures a title in `Shotwell` and exported them, and found out where the metadata is stored that `Shotwell` adds, it is relatively straightforward to put a script together.

Please install `libimage-exiftool-perl`, as that will be necessary for the script.

1. If you use `exiftool -a G1 -s pic.jpg`, you can see all the metadata types and tags embedded within a picture, and also where `Shotwell` places the metadata:

```ini
[XMP-photoshop] Headline                        : 002
[XMP-dc]        Title                           : 002
[IPTC]          Caption-Abstract                : 002
[IPTC]          Headline                        : 002
[IPTC]          OriginatingProgram              : Shotwell
[IPTC]          ProgramVersion                  : 0.13.1+trunk
```

2. Now either the `XMP-photoshop` or the IPTC tags can be used with `exiftool` in our script to show the metadata (and then use that resulting value to rename the file).

Entering `exiftool -IPTC:headline pic.jpg` results in

```ini
Headline                        : 002
```

and this can be parsed with `awk` and fed back as the variable to rename the file:

```bash
mv -i "$i" "$(exiftool -IPTC:headline -s3 "$i").jpg"
```

3. The final script would be like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.jpg; do
  mv -i "$i" "$(exiftool -IPTC:headline -s3 "$i").jpg"
done
```

So, now all your files have been renamed with their `Shotwell` titles, as we see when we examine one with `exiftool -a -G1 -s pic.jpg`:

```bash
ExifTool Version Number         : 9.12
File Name                       : 002.jpg
```

**Notes:**

- The repository version of exiftool is fine, but is quite old, so if you need support for various new features and bugfixes, see [the official site](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/install.html#Unix) for how to build and install the more recent version.
- All of the metadata is preserved unchanged by the script, as only the actual file itself is being renamed.
- The script will obviously only work if your pictures have titles created with Shotwell embedded within them, but it could be adapted for other purposes.

For more general information, see `man exiftool` or [the Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/exiftool.1p.html).